# Stream protected media (located outside of httpdocs) with jPlayer

Tags: php, streaming, jplayer

I have uploaded some sample mp3 files to a directory outside of httpdocs, I have ensured that this is accessible to PHP by configuring open_basedir correctly and tested that this directory is working.

What I would like to do is stream these files via a PHP file as non-authenticated users should never have access to these files. I am currently using jPlayer and expect the setMedia function should look similar to this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "stream.php?track=" + id + ".mp3" });
```

I have tried setting content headers etc in stream.php and it currently looks like this:

```
$filePath = "../song_files/mp3/";
$fileName = "$_GET[track].mp3";

header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');

getFile($filePath + $fileName);
```

If I load this page directly, the mp3 file downloads and plays fine, but when I use the above javascript, jPlayer doesn't play the track.

I have had a look at this post ( [Streaming an MP3 on stdout to Jplayer using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753301/streaming-an-mp3-on-stdout-to-jplayer-using-php) ) and it appears the user was trying to achieve exactly what I want, but upon testing the solution I keep running into a problem, all I get is "CURL Failed".

Are there any different methods I can use to achieve this. Pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around some more I have found a solution that is working fine. I used the code from a similar topic ( [PHP to protect PDF and DOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427457/php-to-protect-pdfs-and-docs) )

I will place the code I used here to help answer the question correctly:

```
//check users is loged in and valid for download if not redirect them out
// YOU NEED TO ADD CODE HERE FOR THAT CHECK
// array of support file types for download script and there mimetype
$mimeTypes = array(
    'doc' => 'application/msword',
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
);
// set the file here (best of using a $_GET[])
$file = "../documents/file.doc";

// gets the extension of the file to be loaded for searching array above
$ext = explode('.', $file);
$ext = end($ext);

// gets the file name to send to the browser to force download of file
$fileName = explode("/", $file);
$fileName = end($fileName);

// opens the file for reading and sends headers to browser
$fp = fopen($file,"r") ;
header("Content-Type: ".$mimeTypes[$ext]);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');

// reads file and send the raw code to browser     
while (! feof($fp)) {
    $buff = fread($fp,4096);
    echo $buff;
}
// closes file after whe have finished reading it
fclose($fp);
</code></pre>
```